# Intersection of a line and arc to a curved surface

Tags: geometry

Intersection of a line with a curved surface.
Can anybody provide me a mathematical way to intersect a line to a curved surface and an arc to a curved surface.

Comment: Are you looking for the implicit function theorem?

Comment: No. Let me explain. 3 points to make a triangle. And I paint this triangle. Building multiple triangles, i create a surface. When the surface that is formed is flat, no issues. When its curved, I couldn't find out where exactly a line that i pass through it, hits the surface.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a *ray-triangle intersection* function.
These are key to computer graphics, and so are widely studied and widely
available. For example:

- The [Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm)
- [Dan Sunday's clear explanation and C++ code](http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html)
- These [lecture notes to a Princeton Univ CS course](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall2000/cs426/lectures/raycast/sld016.htm)
- Etc.

  ---

  [image: RayTriangle]

            

  <sup>(Dan Sunday image.)</sup>

---

Once you have this function in hand, you can simply intersect your ray with every
triangle of your triangulated surface. 
Or, if that is too slow for your application, build a hierarchical data structure of
bounding boxes enclosing sets of triangles, so that you can avoid searching all triangles in a box missed
by the ray.

Intersection of an arc (I presume a circular arc?) with a triangulated
surface is more complex (quadratic vs. linear).
I would first write a circle-plane intersection function, and from that, an
arc-plane function, and from that, an arc-triangle function.